# How should Implementation of Pipeline and Tail command be done in C language?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, tail

How do I write a C program that implements the following commands:

```
tail -5 /etc/passwd | grep e | sort  > result.txt
```

What should the C program contain? How should `r_read` and `r_write` be implemented in the C program?

Answer (score 0):

coreutils are opensource so you can read their sources. Here's a link where you can find sources to coreutils http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src